# Filling in based on other data Automatically

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, missing-data

My goal is filling in NULL in TEMP table(CTE).
For instance, there are 3 lots. Two of the lots happen to have value at RECIPE column.
But Lot L3 doesn't have. However, MATERIAL happens to have same value.
Therefore, in this case, I can fill in the same value(in this case 'R1').
How to modify WITH clause in my code?

```
Expected result is 

"LOTNO" "MATERIAL"  "RECIPE"
------- ---------- --------
"L1"    "M1"    "R1"
"L2"    "M1"    "R1"
"L3"    "M1"    "R1"
```

My code is

```
 CREATE TABLE OUTHISTORY (LOTNO VARCHAR(10), MATERIAL VARCHAR(10), RECIPE VARCHAR(10));
    INSERT INTO OUTHISTORY VALUES('L1','M1','R1');
    INSERT INTO OUTHISTORY VALUES('L2','M1','R1');
    INSERT INTO OUTHISTORY VALUES('L3','M1',NULL);
    
    WITH TEMP AS (
    SELECT * FROM OUTHISTORY  --How to modify here?
    ) SELECT * FROM TEMP;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-use the `with` clause to get the `recipe` value for the same `material` number as,

```
with temp 
as 
(
  select * 
    from outhistory  --How to modify here?
),
temp_with_filled_null
as
(
select lotno,material,
 coalesce (recipe
          ,(select recipe
              from temp i
             where i.lotno != o.lotno
               and i.material = o.material
               and rownum = 1)) recipe
  from temp o
)
select *
  from temp_with_filled_null;
```

Here you may avoid the second with clause but I would suggest to do in this way and second you can use of `FETCH FIRST ROW` instaed of `ROWNUM` if you are using >=12c